# java CSVReader and CSVWriter producing unexpected results

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm using Java CSVReader and CSVWriter from [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inputFile=new File("e:\\temp\\5.csv");
        File outputFile=new File("e:\\temp\\5_out.csv");
        CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        CSVWriter outputWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile),',', '"');
        //CSVWriter outputWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile),',', '"','\\');
        Listlines=reader.readAll();

        outputWriter.writeAll(lines);
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();
        reader.close();
    }
```

input1

```
"\"7 BURY NEW ROAD  MANCHESTER","","","","Prestwich"
```

output1

```
"""7 BURY NEW ROAD  MANCHESTER","","","","Prestwich"
```

I don't understand why the output is like that.  Can someone explain the logic?

If I uncomment the lines where it's commented, basically tells the writer to use '\' to escape quotes and escape characters, it has the following results:

output2

```
"\"7 BURY NEW ROAD  MANCHESTER","","","","Prestwich"
```

I also don't understand why the output is like that.

Comment: That output looks reasonable. What did you expect the output to be like? CSV didn't really have a standard format [until 2005](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) (and even that is just a recommendation, not a rule) and tends to vary a bit between implementations, but traditionally double quotes are escaped with `""`, not `\"`, and RFC4180 specifies `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense. `CSVReader` uses `\` [as escape character](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/CVSreader.htm) and it seems that it can't be changed. Once read, your input starts with the following structure:

```
DELIMITER - ESCAPED_QUOTATION_MARK
```

Your first CSVWriter's escape character is ", so the first output starts with

```
"""
```

Your second CSVWriter escapes with `\`, so

```
"\"
```

the output is.

(is the disappearing MANCHESTER also a part of the issue or just a typo?)